# How can I append html from component to another component in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7

I have in **app.component.html**

```
<nominapp-right-side></nominapp-right-side>
```

in **nominapp-right-side.html** I have

```
<div>aaa</div>
<div id="contenido1"></div>
<div>asdsss</div
```

In **extra-co.html** I have

```
<div>abcdd</div>
```

How can I append from component **extra-co.html** to **nominapp-right-side.html** inside tag `<div id="contenido1"></div>`???

Answer (score 0):

`<extra-co></extra-co>`
You already had this in your example by adding `<nominapp-right-side></nominapp-right-side>` to `app-component.html`

Here's an example of one way I did this:

```
test
<app-navigation align="middle"></app-navigation>
test3
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

'test2' is inside other component and what appears is: [image]

A practical use case of this in my website is adding the navbar to every page: 
`app-component.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<app-navigation></app-navigation>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//In nominapp-right-side.html
<div>aaa</div>
  <div id="contenido1">
  <app-extra-co></app-extra-co>
  </div>
<div>asdsss</div>

//In extra-co.html
<div>abcdd</div>

//In app.component.html
<app-nominapp-right-side></app-nominapp-right-side>
```

Try this

Comment: but the problem is when I need to append other component diferent to extra-co, for example component2.html. diferent components could append inside nominapp-right-side.html